# Gdiplus::PathGradientBrush in an MFC application doesn't draw

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

A "simple" straight-forward code that is mostly a copy-paste from an [article in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534483(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't produce any output. I have added a few more lines (drawing with plain GDI) to make sure the coordinates are correct - those lines work just fine.

The code is changing the background of a `STATIC` control and the drawing is performed in the `OnPaint` handler. The `OnCtlColor` is augmented to return a `NULL_BRUSH` for this `STATIC` control so there's no painting-over done by the framework.

Checking the status of the GDI+ objects and methods (in a debugger and via logging) shows that everything is OK. I'm at a loss, please help solve this puzzle.

Here's the relevant code (removed error handling and `static_cast`'s I have for \W4):

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
Graphics graphics(dc);
CRect rc;
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_GS_COLOR)->GetWindowRect(&rc); // the STATIC to paint
ScreenToClient(&rc);

// GDI+ uses real numbers, not integers
const Rect gdirc = Rect(rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height());

// next 2 lines work just fine - painting a RED background
const SolidBrush solidBrush((ARGB)Color::Red);
graphics.FillRectangle(&solidBrush, gdirc);

const PointF sz(rc.Width() - 1, rc.Height() - 1);
PointF pts[] = {PointF(0, 0), PointF(sz.X, 0), PointF(sz.X, sz.Y), PointF(0, sz.Y)};
PathGradientBrush brush(pts, 4);

Color colors[] = {Color(0, 0, 0), Color(255, 0, 0), Color(0, 255, 0), Color(0, 0, 255)};
int count = 4;
brush.SetSurroundColors(colors, &count);
brush.SetCenterColor(Color(128, 128, 128));

// !!!!! this doesn't fail, returns a status OK, and has NO EFFECT on the image :(
const auto status = graphics.FillRectangle(&brush, gdirc);

// this draws a smaller inner GREEN rectangle, works as expected
rc.DeflateRect(20, 20);
dc.FillSolidRect(&rc, m_rgb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(GDIPLUSENUMS%2FWrapModeClamp);k(WrapModeClamp);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true) on the `WrapMode` enumeration, that is used as a third, default parameter to the brush's constructor, the default value `WrapModeClamp` means:

> **WrapModeClamp**
>   Specifies that no tiling takes place.

Once I added that third parameter to the constructor and specified the `WrapModeTile` value the painting started to occur.

```
Gdiplus::PathGradientBrush brush(pts, 4, WrapModeTile);
```

**OR** use the brush's `TranslateTransform` to properly offset it so it paints the expected pattern! In which case there's no need to specify the tiling as it becomes unnecessary.